# Loading millions of points with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a json dataset with millions of points.The structure is like this:

[[1436997600000,7],[....]]

The first number is a data and second one is a value.
I want to plot this in a highchart so that it doesn't take so much time to load the chart and to navigate in it. I followed this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading

but can't get it work with my data. It take so much time to load and when I zoom the message 'loading from server' doesn't disappear. Can anyone help me on this please?

JS:

```
$(function () {
/**
 * Load new data depending on the selected min and max
 */
function afterSetExtremes(e) {

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/public_html/webservice.php/re/pap/' + Math.round(e.min) + '/' + Math.round(e.max), function (data) {

        chart.series[0].setData(data);

        chart.hideLoading();
    });
}

// See source code from the JSONP handler at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/from-sql.php
$.getJSON('http://localhost/public_html/webservice.php/re/pap', function (data) {

    // Add a null value for the end date
    data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2016, 9, 14, 19, 59), null]]);

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        navigator : {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series : {
                data : data
            }
        },

        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL history by the minute from 1998 to 2011'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Displaying 1.7 million data points in Highcharts Stock by async server loading'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'hour',
                count: 1,
                text: '1h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false, // it supports only days
            selected : 4 // all
        },

        xAxis : {
            events : {
                afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes
            },
            minRange: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
        },

        yAxis: {
            floor: 0
        },

        series : [{
            data : data,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0u5c4pg/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please have a look here https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts

Comment: Here is working chart http://jsfiddle.net/ate7ur9z/

Comment: Have already seen it @SonuR

Comment: I know how to do a highchart.The problem is the lots of points that I have to plot and the chart becames to slow @SonuR

Comment: If `loading` message doesn't disappear, then your AJAX is not working, most probably. Do you have any errors in the console? Is `chart.series[0].setData(data);` even called (put before some `console.log(data)` to check this)?

Comment: The only error that I'm getting is this one:

    Failed to load resource: https://s1.2mdn.net/viewad/3742665/1-     Tracking+Pixel+1x1.gif net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

But it think that this does not interfere with the chart. 
Although, I debug the code with a     console.log(data) before     chart.series[0].setData(data); and nothing happened.

Comment: @PawelFus I've noticed that the message "loading from server" disappear but it takes too long. How can I make it faster?

Comment: So your code actually works? Then it means your data is loading for a long time. Maybe some bottleneck in queries on your backend? Or maybe you load to many points?

Comment: I think its because of retrieving so many points and don't know how to make it efficient.

Comment: @F.Rita I see that you have updated your code (but not linked demos) - do you still have problem with loading data? Or did you resolve that and you have a problem with Highcharts?

Comment: Nop, its working @KacperMadej ! Thanks :)